# What is the best way to relate a bank, many to many ? has_many or has_many_and_belongs_to?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database, has-many

What is best use to make the relationship bank, many to many?

Has_many or has_many_and_belongs_to ?

I have 3 models and Curriculum Vacancy, how is the better way to relate them?

I`m new at ruby on rails, someone can help me ???

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain, but it looks like you're asking whether to use :has_many :through or :has_and_belongs_to_many. While you don't provide enough information about your models or how they should be related to answer, the general rule is this: 
If you want to store data about the association, use :has_many :through. If not, use :has_and_belongs_to_many.